# Getting values from multiple tables using sea-orm

Tags: sea-orm

I'm trying to get values from two related tables using sea-orm. For that I'm using something like:

```rust
let paginator = CeccModel::find()
            .column_as(
                Expr::tbl(Alias::new("cecc_instance"), cecc_instance::Column::CeccId)
                    .into_simple_expr(),
                "cecc_instance_id",
            )
            .column_as(
                Expr::tbl(
                    Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
                    cecc_instance::Column::ContractAddress,
                )
                .into_simple_expr(),
                "contract_address",
            )
            .column_as(
                Expr::tbl(Alias::new("cecc_instance"), cecc_instance::Column::Enabled)
                    .into_simple_expr(),
                "enabled",
            )
            .column_as(
                Expr::tbl(
                    Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
                    cecc_instance::Column::LastBlockSaved,
                )
                .into_simple_expr(),
                "last_block_saved",
            )
            .join_as(
                sea_orm::JoinType::InnerJoin,
                cecc::Relation::CeccInstance.def(),
                Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
            )
            .filter(Condition::any().add(cecc_instance::Column::Enabled.eq(enabled)))
            .paginate(db, results_per_page.try_into().unwrap());


 let t = paginator
            .fetch_page((page - 1).try_into().unwrap())
            .await
            .map(|p| (p, num_pages)); // here I only obtain values from "cecc" table.
```

where cecc_instance table has a foreign key corresponding to a registry in cecc table.

When I execute the query, explained lines above, I only obtain the values associated to cecc table. But no the values I **also** expect from the table cecc_instance.

So I was just wondering if that is the expected behavior or is there something else I am missing or doing wrong.

Please let me know what you think, any help is well received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because sea orm is returns data in Model by default in your case CeccModel. Try getting the result as json instead of CeccModel.

```
let paginator = CeccModel::find()
        .column_as(
            Expr::tbl(Alias::new("cecc_instance"), cecc_instance::Column::CeccId)
                .into_simple_expr(),
            "cecc_instance_id",
        )
        .column_as(
            Expr::tbl(
                Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
                cecc_instance::Column::ContractAddress,
            )
            .into_simple_expr(),
            "contract_address",
        )
        .column_as(
            Expr::tbl(Alias::new("cecc_instance"), cecc_instance::Column::Enabled)
                .into_simple_expr(),
            "enabled",
        )
        .column_as(
            Expr::tbl(
                Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
                cecc_instance::Column::LastBlockSaved,
            )
            .into_simple_expr(),
            "last_block_saved",
        )
        .join_as(
            sea_orm::JoinType::InnerJoin,
            cecc::Relation::CeccInstance.def(),
            Alias::new("cecc_instance"),
        )
        .filter(Condition::any().add(cecc_instance::Column::Enabled.eq(enabled))).into_json() // <- place into_json() before paginate
        .paginate(db, results_per_page.try_into().unwrap());


 let t = paginator
        .fetch_page((page - 1).try_into().unwrap())
        .await
        .map(|p| (p, num_pages));
```

Check sea-orm docs for more info:
https://www.sea-ql.org/SeaORM/docs/basic-crud/json/